# Spring Controller: how to get the query parameters and urlencoded body separately

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a POST controller to handle a simple HTML user sign up form that has fields for 'username', 'password' and so on. This is sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. The controller also takes a few parameters from the request URI, like the client id, redirect uri and it might have a `username` query parameter which is used to prefill the 'username' input when rendering the page.

In my controller, I use a model to read the request body called `UserSignUpFormModel` it's a simple POJO with setters and getters for the form fields 'username', 'password', 'email'.

However, when the form is submitted with also a `username` query parameter, then the username value is added twice to the 'username' field in `UserSignUpFormModel`.

When performing this POST request:

```
POST localhost/sign-up?client_id=abc&redirect_uri=xyz&username=bar

-- Request body:
username=foo&password=some_password&...
```

then calling `userSignUpFormModel.getUsername()` returns `"foo,bar"` instead of just "foo" from the request body.

This is my controller:

```java
@PostController
public String performSignUp(UserSignUpFormModel user) {
     // username = "foo,bar" but should just be "foo" from the input field
     String username = user.getUsername();
     // ...controller logic
}
```

And this is my model:

```java
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class UserSignUpFormModel {

    private String email;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    private String passwordConfirmation;

    private Boolean hasAcceptedTerms;

}
```

How can I get the query parameters and body values separately?

Comment: `calling userSignUpFormModel.getUsername() returns "foo,bar" instead of just "foo" from the request body.`  Why is that so unexpected? you're assigning both 'foo' and 'bar' to a query parameter called 'username'. Maybe you should stop sending the requestbody as a string of query parameters. I'm sure that would solve the problem. Send it as a JSON object string instead.

Comment: @Maurice It is unexpected because the query parameters and the request body should not be intertwined with each other. They are two separate parts of the request so why Spring is grouping them under the same object makes no sense. Indeed, sending the data as JSON would solve the problem, but I am working with a HTML form on the front-end that sends its data as x-www-form-urlencoded so that is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried adding an additional request param argument to the signature?

Comment: What is the intended behavior when the value is provided in both places? Does one take precedence?

Comment: Why are you even posting to the URL including the username parameter? The problem is imho not the parsing but the way you are posting/pre-populating the form.

Comment: The reason was that it would post to the exact same endpoint that is accessed with GET. However I realized it indeed makes no sense and it is better to add only the necessary parameters to the “action” attribute, this prevents this problem.